# How do I use this fact to find $\sin^5\theta$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have a complex number, $z,$ which has a modulus of $1$ and argument of $\theta$.

The first part is to show that $z^n-\frac{1}{z^n}=2i \sin(n\theta)$, which I have done.

The next question is this:
Hence show that $\sin^5\theta = \frac{1}{16}(\sin 5\theta - 5\sin3\theta + 10\sin\theta)$

How would I use the first part to show the second?

Comment: You can use here exponential form of a a complex number

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Put $n=5,3,1$ in $$z^n-\dfrac1{z^n}=2i\sin(n\theta)$$

and calculate $$\sin5\theta-5\sin3\theta+10\sin\theta$$

Comment: How would I calculate that from the substitution step? I'm not seeing how I get to sin5θ−5sin3θ+10sinθ from 2isin(5θ), 2isin(3θ) and 2isin(θ), what am I doing to get rid of the i's?

Comment: @JoshuaPeacham $z^n-\frac{1}{z^n}=2i \sin(n\theta)$ implies $\sin(n\theta) = -\frac i2\left( z^n-\frac{1}{z^n}\right)$; can you see why? The next question is, what is another way to write $\sin^5 \theta$?

Comment: @DavidK I get the first part, for another way to write $\sin^5\theta$, I wrote $\sin^5\theta$ as $(z-\frac{1}{z})^5$ and used binomial expansion to expand it out, and that gave me the correct answer, but I didn't need to use $\sin(n\theta)=-\frac{i}{2}(z^n-\frac{1}{z^n})$

Comment: @JoshuaPeacham $\sin^5 \theta \neq (z-\frac{1}{z})^5.$ It seems likely that you made multiple errors that happened to cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Use $$\left(z-\dfrac 1z\right)^5=z^5-\dfrac 1{z^5}-\binom51\left (z^3-\dfrac 1{z^3}\right)+\binom 52\left (z -\dfrac 1z\right)$$ as $$\binom  nr =\binom  n{n-r}$$

Now put $n=1,3,5$